# Should Closeable be used as the Java equivalent for .NET's IDisposable?

Tags: java, idisposable

**Update**: As @PaulGroke points out below, things have changed with Java 7: there now is [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Which isn't tied to streams and supported by the new [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct.

`AutoCloseable` is the direct Java equivalent for .NET's `IDisposable` interface.

---

The `Closeable` interface introduced in Java 1.5 is tightly tied to streams, and even has an exception specifier for `IOException`. This suggests that it should only be used for streams or other IO related activities, rather than general purpose cleanup logic.

Certainly the description for the `close()` method would make absolutely no sense outside of a stream/IO context:

> `void close() throws IOException`
>
> *Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it.*

Should I therefore declare my own interface, `Disposable`, with a `Dispose()` method on it, and use that as an analogue to .NET's `IDisposable` interface? Or should I re-use `Closeable` even though it may not be a perfect fit?

Comment: @Pharap There are two separate patterns for implementing `IDisposable` mentioned on the page you link to. Implementing `Object.Finalize()` is only required in the relatively rare scenario that your object is directly responsible for allocating unmanaged resources (i.e. native resources which are not wrapped with a SafeHandle). Your statement that ".NET's recommended way to implement `IDisposable` [...] requires use of `Object.Finalize()`" is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Especially given that close() throws an IOException you then have to write exception handling code for, I would advise you write your own interface. This interface can then throw any checked exceptions that are appropriate to the use you want to put the interface to.

Interfaces tend to signify intent in the mind of the reader, so having a class implement an IO-associated Closeable interface will make the reader assume the class is also IO-based.

Obviously, if the objects you do want to close *are* all IO-related, you should use Closeable. But otherwise go for

```
/** Interface for objects that require cleanup post-use. Call dispose() in finally block! */
public interface Disposable {
    public void dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 50):

I'm sure most people are aware of it, but since this question is still among the top results when searching for "IDisposable Java" (#2 result for me just now), and it's still not mentioned here...

Things have changed with Java 7: there now is [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). Which isn't tied to streams and supported by the new [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construct.

Comment: While I find it irksome that Java has taken so long to get the equivalent of `IDisposable`, and I regarded the lack of such a construct as a significant flaw in Java, I laud the creators of Java for recognizing the need to allow both try-block exceptions and cleanup expressions to be propagated up the call stack.  My own preference would have been to have `try-with-resources` wrap any exceptions that occur in the cleanup block in a `CleanupFailedException` (which would indicate what exception--if any--occurred in the `try` block, along with a list of cleanup exceptions)...

Comment: ...and also provide a means by which cleanup code could tell whether it the `try` block had succeeded or failed (for example, if an exception is thrown by code which is modifying something guarded by a lock, the lock should often be neither released nor held indefinitely, but should instead be invalidated so that any pending or future attempt to acquire the lock will throw an immediate `badLockExitException`; it would be helpful if a try-with-resources construct could let a locking object implement such semantics automatically).

Comment: I tend to agree, though the reason is for backward compatibility to allow [Closeable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) to extend [AutoCloseable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html). One thing to consider is that if an exception is thrown in the body and the cleanup also throws an exception the bubbled exceptions [getSuppressed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed--) contains the exception from [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close--).

Answer (score 1):

When implementing `Closeable` (or `AutoClosable` for that matter) in a class it's also possible to just omit the throws declaration:

```
class X implements Closeable {
    @Override public void close() /* I don't throw */ {

    }
}
```

So when someone is using a typed object they can call `close()` without having to catch anything:

```
void f() { // notice no need for throws because close() doesn't throw
    X x = new X();
    try {
        // do something
    } finally {
        x.close();
    }
}
```

It is also compatible with anything expecting a `Closeable`: if this object is passed into somewhere that handles `Closeable`, they already anticipate an exception and handle it correctly, albeit futilely in this case.

This includes libraries like [Guava `Closeables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closeables.html) and Java 7 try-with-resources as Paul Groke suggests:

```
try (X x = new X()) {
    // do something
}
```

---

There's a rare caveat though: you can't reintroduce the exception in child-classes once it's stripped:

```
class Y extends X {
                                  /* compile error */
    @Override public void close() throws IOException {
        // Y.close clashes with X.close: overridden method does not throw IOException
    }
}
```